# Handle Multiple useState Calls On The Same Object In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am designing an application that work with Slacks API and my own custom API to upload pictures automatically to a specified Slack channel. I configured the APIs and they work properly, but I am having trouble with the frontend of my application which is built in React. The component I'm having trouble with should:

1. Fetch the available Slack channels and map generate `<option>` elements within a `<select>` element.
2. Allow the user to select which directory the want to Upload files (due to limitations with the `webkitdirectory` property, I am using splice to truncate the selected folder to just get the directory name, instead of the directory its files e.g. "Desktop" instead of "Desktop/IMG101")
3. Allow the user to select from the channels generated in the first step.
4. Allow the user to click the upload button, which submits a post request that sends a "state" object with the ID of the channel selected and the directory selected to the API

Where I am encountering issues is storing and passing the "state" from the channel and directory. I used a useState function with an object that has the properties of "dir" and "channel":

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
        dir:'',
        channel:''
    })
```

Then I have two functions that handle selecting the directory and channel that first spread the previous state using a callback function, then add the new state:

```
const handleFolderChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const folderPath = e.target.files[0].webkitRelativePath;
        const folderDir = folderPath.split('/');
        setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, dir: folderDir[0]}));
    }
    const handleChannelChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const channel = e.target.value;
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, channel: channel }));
        };
```

In theory, this should update the state object with each value when selected, but what I encounter is that when one selection is made, the object is reset to the original form with "dir" and "channel" containing empty strings, leaving the object with on one value (e.g. `{'dir': '', 'channel': 'channelID'` or `{'dir': 'IMG_Folder', 'channel': ''`).

And further, when I use the "Upload" button that handles the post request, the object passed to the API is simply:

```
{
        dir:'',
        channel:''
    }
```

I initially was using separate useState calls to store the states for "channel" and "dir" but I read about how useState is asynchronous and switch to containing both values in one useState call, which should have fixed my problem but it hasn't and I have no idea why. [useState is Async](https://www.andreadiotallevi.com/blog/how-to-handle-multiple-set-state-calls-on-the-same-object-in-react). Any help would be greatly appreciated! The full code for this component is here:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function Clickable ({ type }) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        dir:'',
        channel:''
    })
   
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getChannels");
        const data = await response.json();
        setOptions(data);
    }
    const handleFolderChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const folderPath = e.target.files[0].webkitRelativePath;
        const folderDir = folderPath.split('/');
        setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, dir: folderDir[0]}));
    }
    const handleChannelChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const channel = e.target.value;
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, channel: channel }));
        };

        const handleFileUpload = async () => {
            try {
                if (state.dir && state.channel) {
                  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/uploadFiles", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                      "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                      channel: state.channel,
                      dir: state.dir,
                    }),
                  });
          
                  if (response.ok) {
                    console.log("Upload successful!");
                    console.log(await response.text());
                  } else {
                    console.log("Upload failed!");
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log("Please select both a folder and a channel.");
                }
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error uploading file:", error);
              }
            };

    
    if (type === 'path') {
        return (
            <input
                type="file"
                id="dir"
                webkitdirectory="true"
                directory=''
                onChange={handleFolderChange}
            />
        )
    }

    if (type === 'channel') {
        return (
                <select
                    name="channels"
                    id="channels"
                    onChange={handleChannelChange}
                >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Channel</option>
                {options.map((option) => (<option key={option[0]} value={option[0]}>{option[1]}</option>))}
                </select>
        )
    }   
    
    if (type === 'upload') {
            return (
                <button onClick={handleFileUpload}>Upload</button>

            )
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `type` in props? It looks like you need to lift state up to the parent that is sending `type`. Make sure the component isn't being unmounted and replaced with an identical component. You can add a `console.log` in your useEffect to check.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I just want to clarify some things. Type in props is prop value thats passed from the `App` component to the `Clickable` component. The type can be a string of either "path", "channel", or "upload" (e.g. `<Clickable type={'path'} /> ` to specify the path variant of the Clickable component). By lifting the state, do you mean defining it in the `App` component instead? I will try the `console.log`, thanks.

Comment: It took a bit reading, but I figured out what you meant by lifting state up. I did just that, and got my code to work as intended, thanks so much you're a lifesaver! :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you find the resources you needed!